# Find function $f$ such that $(x-y)(f'(x)-g'(y)) \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities

While working out some thermodynamics, I came across the following problem, which may be viewed as a functional inequality:

> Prove/disprove the existence of a differentiable function $f$ such that
>   $$\Phi(x,y) = (x-y)\, (f'(x)-g'(y)) \geq 0, \qquad \forall\; (x, y)\in \Bbb R^2$$
>   for a given differentiable function $g$.

In the case where $g$ is *convex*, then the choice $f = g$ ends the proof.

**Question:** What happens if $g$ is *not convex*, e.g., if $g$ has an inflection point at $y=0$?

**Attempt:** Let us consider an example. In the case $g(y) = \frac13 y^3$, we look for $f$ such that
\begin{aligned}
\Phi(x,y) &= (x-y)\, (f'(x) - y^2) \\
&= x f'(x) - f'(x) y - x y^2 + y^3 \geq 0 \, .
\end{aligned}
By expanding $\Phi$ as a polynomial function of $y$, one observes that $\Phi$ becomes negative as $y \to {-\infty}$ for fixed $x$. Hence, there is no such function $f$. $\square$

The same conclusion is obtained for any function $g$ such that $y g'(y)$ decreases faster than identity as $y\to -\infty$.
Nevertheless, this argument does not work for $g(y) = \tanh y$ for instance.

Can we find an appropriate $f$ in some particular cases? Or is it always impossible as soon as $g$ is nonconvex?

Comment: Oh, yeah, got my terms wrong. You'd need for $y<x$ that $f'(x)>y^2$ and thus that $f'(x)$ is larger than every positive real number.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. I'd include the polynomial comment in your answer.

Comment: Repeated from deleted comment. The above means that if $x<y$ you need $f'(x)<g'(y)$ and if $x>y$ then you need $f'(x)>g'(y).$ In particular, $g'$ is continuous, you get that for $y<x<y+\delta$ then $g'(y)<f'(x)<g'(y+\delta)$ and thus $\lim_{x\to y^+} f'(x) = g'(y)$ and similarly $\lim_{x\to y^{-}} f'(x)=g'(y).$ So $\lim_{x\to y} f'(x)=g'(y).$

Comment: In particular, when $f'$ is continuous at $y,$ $f'(y)=g'(y).$ So to get an answer which is not $f'=g'$ you need $g'$ to have a lot of discontinuities, which is hard.